# chars array in integer representation

Tags: c, binary, ascii

I'm reading post about *pointers* in **C** [here>>>](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2012/11/c-pointers-explained-really.html), and there is one example:

```
main() {
    ...
    char name[] = "Bill";
    int *q;
    ...
    q = name;
    printf("%d\n", *q);
    ...
```

Which gives me next result:

```
$ ./pointers_explained 
1819044162
```

So question is about next explanation from author:

> (to see how, line up the binary representation of the ascii values for
>   those 4 characters, and then run the 32 bits together, and convert
>   that resultant binary number as an integer.)

Binary for the "Bill" will be:

- **B**: 01000010
- **i**: 01101001
- **l**: 01101100
- **l**: 01101100

(from an ASCII binary table [here>>>](http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html))

What I can't get is:

> and then run the 32 bits together, and convert that resultant binary number as an integer

So - how can I convert this "*Bill*"'s binary into the decimal (or any other ) integer "1819044162"?

Comment: note that this is **undefined behaviour**, the "explanation" is details of some particular compiler and system

Comment: @M.M Yeah, thanks for the clarification, just wondering about how it's working in total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ascii code, "Bill" is

```
B: 0x42
i: 0x69
l: 0x6c
l: 0x6c
```

1819044162 in hex mode is `0x6c6c6942`, this is because of the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

In memory, "Bill" is stored as:

```
     B   i   l   l
name 42  69  6c  6c
```

But if it is little endianness, and reads an 4-byte integer from address `name`, it reads backwards, results `0x6c6c6942`, which is 1819044162.

If the system is big endian, it will results `0x42696c6c`.

Comment: Nice explanation, but it is good to say that this can have alignment problems.